# Select where rows exist more than once with variation

Tags: php, mysql

This is a hard one to put a title to so I apologise for ambiguity.

I have the following MySQL table (it's a Magento table):

```
id    attr_id  store_id   entity_id     value
----+---------+---------+------------+------------------------
1   45      0           173         Sale Gifts + Apartment
2   45      0           175         Sale Outerwear
3   45      1           175         Sale Outerwear
4   45      0           177         (null)
5   45      1           177         New Arrivals
6   45      0           178         New Tops
7   45      1           178         New Tops
```

As you can see, some of the rows have the same everything except `store_id`.

I want to do the following:

1. If a row with `store_id = 0` has a duplicate row, but with `store_id = 1` and different values (for example, rows 4 and 5 above), update the row with `store_id = 0` to have the same value as the other.
2. Delete the row with `store_id = 1`

I know I will probably need a combination of both PHP and MySQL for this. I just don't know what the MySQL query would be.

Any help would be great!

**EDIT**

The end goal from the above table is the following

```
id    attr_id  store_id   entity_id     value
----+---------+---------+------------+------------------------
1   45      0           173         Sale Gifts + Apartment
2   45      0           175         Sale Outerwear
4   45      0           177         New Arrivals
6   45      0           178         New Tops
```

Comment: Can you please add an example how your result should look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrive redundunt values having the same entity_id, you can do :

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  magento m1, magento m2
WHERE 
   m1.attr_id=m2.attr_id
AND
   m1.entity_id=m2.entity_id
AND 
   m1.id > m2.id
```

And for fixing null values, you will need to loop the above results and search for the null and replace it with the previous or next result.

Comment: Whilst this didn't do everything I needed it to, it was a massive help. If there is interest in the question I will put my full code up. Thank you